# Multiple accounts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to play minecraft with my brother and I wanted to see if there's any possible way to make another account from the same email. Is that possible or do we have to purchase minecraft again? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to purchase Minecraft again unfortunately.

Comment: @aman207 it depends what device your on. PC: yes, IOS: No ANDROID: don't know

Comment: if you are using gmail just add plus signs or pluses to the email address.

Comment: There is no way to do this sadly unless you are wanting to download a cracked launcher. (Both playing on the same account is possible if only one of you plays multiplayer and the other one singleplayer)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to have two different account from the same email, If you want a new account, you will have to purchase Minecraft again, with new email.